# Uncaught TypeError: signalR.httpConnection is not a constructor

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I am trying to get all connected users with Identity but it says the error as title which is : `Uncaught TypeError: signalR.httpConnection is not a constructor`

For this line :

```
let hubUrl = '/chatHub'
let httpConnection = new signalR.httpConnection(hubUrl);
let hubConnection = new signalR.hubConnection(httpConnection);

hubConnection.on('SetUsersOnline', usersOnline => {
    if (usersOnline.length > 0) {
        $('#onlineUsers').innerText = '';
        $.each(usersOnline, function (i, user) {

            addUserOnline(user);

        });

    }

});

hubConnection.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax for SignalR was changed quite often and it's hard to tell what is and isn't correct for what version. Just update to latest SignalR and try this:

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                    .withUrl("/chatHub")
                    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
                    .build();

connection.on('SetUsersOnline', usersOnline => {
    if (usersOnline.length > 0) {
        $('#onlineUsers').innerText = '';
        $.each(usersOnline, function (i, user) {
            addUserOnline(user);
        });
    }
});

connection.start().catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
```

Comment: Best bet is to follow the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/?view=signalr-js-latest